# GUI PySide6 and Arduino Uno

Tags: python, pyserial, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, pyside6

I have problem implementing thread logic in my GUI. I created 2 different apps that are used to control the RGB diodes on one port (COM3) . Now I need to add them to my main GUI app, and I need to use Worker(QThread) to make it work. My apps have some basic functions like turn_off, turn_on, set_color, change_color etc.. Tried it like this, but it isn't working. Getting the "raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)" problem.

```
   class Worker(QThread):
    signalData = Signal(str)
    signalFinished = Signal()
   
    
    def run(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
        while self.ser.is_open:
            try:
                text = self.ser.readline().decode().rstrip('\n')
                self.signalData.emit(text)
                self.control_led(text)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error during serial communication: {e}")
                break
        self.ser.close()
        self.signalFinished.emit()
    
    def control_led(self, command):
        if command == 'turn_on':
            self.ser.write(b'1\n')
        elif command == 'turn_off':
            self.ser.write(b'0\n')
        elif command.startswith('analogWrite'):
            _, pin, intensity = command.split()
            self.analog_write(int(pin), int(intensity))
 @Slot()
    def start_com(self):
        

        self.th = Worker()
        
        self.th.signalFinished.connect(self.th.deleteLater)
        self.th.start()

    @Slot()
    def stop_com(self):
        if self.th is not None:
            self.th.quit()
            self.th.wait()
            self.th.serial.close()
    @Slot()
    def send(self, command):
        
        
        if self.light_tab.turn_on():
            text = "turn_on"
            self.signalDataSend(text)
        elif self.light_tab.turn_off():
            text = "turn_off"
            self.signalDataSend(text)
            
        if self.th is not None and command:
            self.th.writeData(command)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your attempts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.